# Executing regex statements over object-array with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, angularjs, validation, angularjs-scope

I'm looking to use regex to do some form manipulation based on the user's credit card input (note: this is only front-end validation for the sake of UX, another service and API handles actual credit card validation).

I'd like to create a $watch statement or some equivalent to match a user's input in the credit card field against several regex statements that are ascribed to different card types.

So, my question in a nutshell is: what's the best pattern to implement that can match against multiple regent statements without degrading performance with too many watchers? My first thought was to write multiple `if` or `switch` statements, but that seems like a problem for extensibility and a complicated bit of logic isn't often the best solution.

Thanks everyone!

Here's what I have so far:

```
    var defaultFormat = /(\d{1,4})/g;

    $scope.cards = [{
        type: 'maestro',
        pattern: /^(5018|5020|5038|6304|6759|676[1-3])/,
        format: defaultFormat,
        length: [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        cvcLength: [3],
        luhn: true
    }, {
        type: 'dinersclub',
        pattern: /^(36|38|30[0-5])/,
        format: defaultFormat,
        length: [14],
        cvcLength: [3],
        luhn: true
    }, {
        type: 'laser',
        pattern: /^(6706|6771|6709)/,
        format: defaultFormat,
        length: [16, 17, 18, 19],
        cvcLength: [3],
        luhn: true
    }, {
        type: 'jcb',
        pattern: /^35/,
        format: defaultFormat,
        length: [16],
        cvcLength: [3],
        luhn: true
    }, {
        type: 'unionpay',
        pattern: /^62/,
        format: defaultFormat,
        length: [16, 17, 18, 19],
        cvcLength: [3],
        luhn: false
    }, {
        type: 'discover',
        pattern: /^(6011|65|64[4-9]|622)/,
        format: defaultFormat,
        length: [16],
        cvcLength: [3],
        luhn: true
    }, {
        type: 'mastercard',
        pattern: /^5[1-5]/,
        format: defaultFormat,
        length: [16],
        cvcLength: [3],
        luhn: true
    }, {
        type: 'amex',
        pattern: /^3[47]/,
        format: /(\d{1,4})(\d{1,6})?(\d{1,5})?/,
        length: [15],
        cvcLength: [3, 4],
        luhn: true
    }, {
        type: 'visa',
        pattern: /^4/,
        format: defaultFormat,
        length: [13, 16],
        cvcLength: [3],
        luhn: true
    }];
```

I also have a luhn algorithm that I can use to check the credit cards.

```
luhnCheck = function(num) {
var digit, digits, odd, sum, _i, _len;
odd = true;
sum = 0;
digits = (num + '').split('').reverse();
for (_i = 0, _len = digits.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  digit = digits[_i];
  digit = parseInt(digit, 10);
  if ((odd = !odd)) {
    digit *= 2;
  }
  if (digit > 9) {
    digit -= 9;
  }
  sum += digit;
}
return sum % 10 === 0;
};
```

Comment: Why not just use one `$watch` and get the type of your card when the model changes?

Comment: That could work; I'm a bit new to JS/Angular, so I'm wondering how you'd implement executing the regex statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/8xpuZ38qALyyV9oRuUT1?p=preview)

You're right, you'd want to watch the value of a model in order to change the "type" stored in a variable somewhere.

Here's an example of a relevant watch statement:

```
    $scope.$watch( 'model', function()
    {
      var found = false;

      angular.forEach( $scope.cards, function( item, index )
      {
        if ( $scope.model.match( item.pattern ) )
        {
          $scope.card_type = item.type;
          found = true;
        }
      });

      // You could run your Luhn method here too

      if ( !found ) $scope.card_type = 'none';
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help and especially the plunker. I can see your solution works and will probably implement a version of it. One question though, if you you don't mind: what role does the HTTP GET request play? Is there a way to do the same action without JSON-ifying anything or making an additional request? Thanks again!

Comment: @markimus Whoops good question, that was cruft left behind when I tried to throw the `$scope.cards` array into a .json file, but I think .json requires quotes around the keys, unlike JS. I've updated the Plunker; totally ignore the `$http` bit.

Comment: Gotcha! I suppose I could have just nixed it and seen what would of happen, but I thought I would ask anyways. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is an untested solution:

On the credit card input form field:

```
<input type="text" ng-change="matchCCTypes()" ng-model="ccnum">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.ccnum = "";
$scope.ccType = null;

$scope.matchCCTypes() = function() {
  $scope.ccType = null;
  angular.forEach($scope.cards, function(cardType) {
    // pseudo code:
    // if ($scope.ccnum matches current pattern) {
    //   $scope.ccType = cardType.type
    // }
  });
};
```

This way, you can avoid setting up a watcher. The function will run only when the `ccnum` field changes.